# correct wiring solution

Tags: hvac

Purchased a Goodman GMT090-4B 90,000btu furnace used that was assured to operate perfectly, it looks brand new.
There are 4 wires that come out the side of the housing that were used for power and thermostat I'm told. Can someone identify what wires go to where? BLUE, GREEN, RED, and WHITE, this will be used in my garage and has no future plans for A/C. All replies greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Power uses BIG wires (at least 12 AWG). Thermostat uses small wires (typically 18 AWG). Color schemes are quite different. Pictures might help. But generally you would have two totally separate groups of wires for power and for thermostat.

Comment: all the wires are the same size coming from furnace

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in question?

Answer (score 3):

A typical American forced-air furnace has TWO complete electrical systems in it, separated by a small transformer.

The AC mains electrical system has 3 wires typically, and needs to be hard-wired to a dedicated circuit into standard 120V electrical. These need to be run in 14 AWG or larger AC mains quality cable (Romex or UF or BX or EMT conduit).  The 3 wires are:

- Black (always-hot @ 120V)
- White (neutral of 120V supply)
- Green or bare (safety ground)

The "Low voltage" electrical system has 2-5 wires typically, depending on what it supports in terms of features and thermostat.  These are low-voltage and can be run in 18 AWG thermostat cable.

- "R" typically Red: Supply from transformer, 24 volts AC
- "W" typically White: Call For Heat, connect to R to operate furnace
- "G" typically Green: Call for Fan/Blower to run (irrespective of furnace)
- "Y" typically Yellow: Call for Air Conditioning
- "C" ??? color preferably blue: "Common" (other side of transformer)

R and C are the two legs of the transformer, giving 24 volts between them.  Normal thermostats don't need C, but smart 'stats typically do.

To make a call for any of those things, the thermostat shunts (shorts) the R wire to the W, G or Y wires as appropriate.  If you just twisted R and W together with a wire nut, the furnace would run continuously, which would be great for the first 2 hours, but then you'd get sweated out of the place.  Anyway a $10 thermostat can take care of shorting R and W at appropriate times.  Basic thermostats are stupid simple.

American furnaces don't do air conditioning, but they do provide the air handling for the air conditioning. So they typically provide a terminal lug for the Y wire that does nothing, just to provide a convenient place to attach the A/C wires.

If you ever have thoughts toward getting an air conditioner, get a heat pump instead.  Difference is,  heat pumps are much more efficient (cheaper to run), and they also heat.  If it's warm enough for ice to melt, they heat more efficiently than gas. Also, they give you a hedge from what may happen 10 years from now with gas and electric prices. So you're not "married to gas".